# Removing Welcome message from magento 2 - just xml

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, header

I've started to work on Magento 2 and get my head around it, I'm really familiar with Magento 1 and removing the welcome message was no big deal.

However all I've found the location of the welcome message in the header, but can't seem to find the XML to remove the block from the header.

Is it possible to remove the welcome message with the XML or do I need to simply comment out the switch inside of the `header.phtml` file?

Comment: The one that says `Default welcome msg!`, and displays in the top right, correct?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The welcome message is in `html/header.phtml` and the block is referenced from this XML file: `/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`. The template is referenced by the `$_template` property within the `\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header` block.

If you want to maintain some of the customer welcome functionality, you will need to override the template. However, if you want to remove that, you have two options. First, you can keep the header intact and just hide the welcome message with XML like this (`ThemeNamespace/ThemeDirectory/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`):

```
<referenceBlock name="header">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">other</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

If you want to completely remove the `header.phtml` file altogether, the following XML in the same place should do that:

```
<referenceBlock name="header" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: Cool thats great. Makes sense now :)

Comment: What if I want to move it to different place

Comment: @Omer, I would try <move />: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_mv

Comment: Hi there! @bassplayer7, I'm really happy I came across this as this explanation is the closest I've gotten to my own question. Would you be able to help me out? I've located these files you've talked above above, however I'm really only looking to move JUST the welcome message. I'd like to have it full width above the header. So ideally I'd like to do something like: <move element="welcome.message" destination="header.panel"  before="-"/> but alas I do not know the hook for the welcome message. Are you able to provide any help on this?

Comment: @kia4567, the welcome message is *in* the header template. My suggestion would be to hide it as described above and then add another block in the desired location with the same block class but different name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @bassplayer7! I've removed it no problem but it seems I may not understand as well as I'd like to add it in again. I went to add it in my default.xml under the remove code you said to put in like this: <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="header.message" as="header" before="-" />
        </referenceContainer>. I thought that was how to do it but it must not be. How might I change this up to add that block you were talking about? Thanks!

Comment: @kia4567, I don't think I have enough context to get a sufficient idea of what is not working. I suggest asking a new question with example code, and very specific details of the problem to see if someone can help out.

Comment: @bassplayer7 I actually opened one up here, do you think you could look at it? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/247546/re-position-just-the-welcome-message/247570#247570

Comment: I've actually just figured it out (with some of your help and the other person that helped me out). For future, anyone looking to completely MOVE the welcome message somewhere else, check this question/answer out here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/247546/re-position-just-the-welcome-message/247570#247570

Answer (score 3):

In your theme 'your_theme/Magento_theme/layout/default.xml' add below code

```
 <referenceBlock name="header.panel.wrapper" remove="true"/>
```